# Melava Malka on Motzei Shabbos

Tags: halacha, meal-seudah, motzei-shabbos

Should one have a fixed, formal meal for [Melava Malka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melaveh_Malkah) on Motzei Shabbos?

Comment: [Yes, there does appear to be such an idea](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3837/5). Care to elaborate on the question?

Answer (score 7):

An idea (lechatchila), yes, and meat as well.  Though they are not strict requirements. ([Mishna Berura 300:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=155), [Aruch haShulchan 300:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9101&st=&pgnum=161))

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, one should eat a kezayis of bread. If not possible, a kezayis of mezonos or fruit will also do, but to eat bread is much better.

Comment: Users of the site normally include a source for their answers. How about including http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Melaveh_Malka which says "What should one eat for Melava Malka?
"One should try to eat bread for Melava Malka, but if he cannot then cake is sufficient. If he cannot even eat cake he should at least have some fruits or vegetables."

Comment: so bread is not the very least?